# $\langle v, \, A w \rangle \stackrel{?}{=} \langle A v, \, w \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two vectors $v, \, w \in V$ belonging to vector space $V$ endowed with inner product $\langle \cdot, \, \cdot \rangle$ and basis $B_V$, does the identity $\langle v, \, A w \rangle \stackrel{?}{=} \langle A v, \, w \rangle$ hold true, for arbitrary matrix $A \in M_{n \times n}$?

Comment: No. Matrices for which this holds are called self-adjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, take $V = \Bbb R^2$ (or $\Bbb C^2$ if you prefer), let $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denote the standard "dot-product", and let
$$
v = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad w = \pmatrix{0\\1}, \quad A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$
Then $\langle v,Aw \rangle = 1$, but $\langle Av,w \rangle = 0$.

In general, it will hold (for a given $A$) that $\langle Av,w \rangle = \langle v,Aw \rangle$ for all $v,w \in V$ if and only if $A$ is *self-adjoint* relative to the inner product. For the standard inner product, this means that the matrix of $A$ is symmetric (or Hermitian for complex matrices).

Comment: I thank you for the answer.

Comment: 12 views in less the 7 minutes. :O

Answer (score 0):

Is $V$ an abstract vector space or $\mathbf R^n$ (or $F^n$ for a field $F$)? It makes no sense to say $A$ is a *matrix* if $V$ is not the vector space of column vectors.

Supposing $V = \mathbf R^n$ and the inner product on $V$ is the standard dot  product, the correct formula relating an $n \times n$ real matrix $A$ to that inner product uses the matrix transpose:
$$
Av \cdot w = v \cdot A^\top w
$$
for all $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbf R^n$. So we have $Av \cdot w = v \cdot Aw$ if and only if
$$
v \cdot Aw = v \cdot A^\top w,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
v \cdot (Aw - A^\top w) = 0.
$$
For this to hold for all $v$ means $Aw - A^\top w = O$, and for that to hold for all $w$ means $A = A^\top$: $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

This is one of the most important properties of matrix transposes. It is even true if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, where $v$ is in $\mathbf R^n$, $w$ is in $\mathbf R^m$, the dot product on the left is in $\mathbf R^m$, and the dot product on the right is in $\mathbf R^n$.

On a general inner product space $V$, the generalization of the first displayed formula above to a linear map $A : V \to V$ uses the adjoint map $A^*$ in place of transposes:
$$
\langle Av,w\rangle = \langle v,A^*w\rangle 
$$
for all $v$ and $w$ in $V$, and in fact this equation (quantified over all $v$ and $w$ in $V$) *defines* what the adjoint $A^*$ is. And we have $\langle Av,w\rangle = \langle v,Aw\rangle$ for all $v$ and $w$ in $V$ if and only if $A=A^*$: $A$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: How does it relates to the adjugate of a matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: No relation. That is just an example of one word (adjoint) being used for different concepts and the reason for using the alternate word “adjugate” is to avoid possible confusion since these two ways of using “adjoint” are in the same area of math.